# ScrollView doesn't display whole TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-tablelayout

I want to display a `TableLayout` within a `ScrollView`. The Table has 9 `TableRow`s but the `ScrollView` starts displaying parts of the 4th row and I can't sroll up to see the rows above.

The XML-Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/uyi_choosepi_relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" >

    <MyGallery
        android:id="@+id/uyi_gallery_originals"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/uyi_choosepi_buttontable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

        <TableRow >
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hilfe"
                android:onClick="showHelp"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/uyi_choosepi_savepw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fertig"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="savePassword"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/uyi_choosepi_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/uyi_gallery_originals"
        android:layout_above="@id/uyi_choosepi_buttontable">

            <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/uyi_choosepi_tablelayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:shrinkColumns="0,1,2" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `TableRow`s in the `uyi_choosepi_tablelayout` where added programmatically as follows:

```
table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.uyi_choosepi_tablelayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < UYIMainActivity.PASS_LENGTH; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(table.getContext());

            originalViews[i] = new ImageView(row.getContext());
            originalViews[i].setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            originalViews[i].setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            originalViews[i].setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
            originalViews[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.oempty);

            distortedViews[i] = new ImageView(row.getContext());
            distortedViews[i].setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            distortedViews[i].setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            distortedViews[i].setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
            distortedViews[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.wempty);

            ImageView arrow = new ImageView(row.getContext());
            arrow.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            arrow.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            arrow.setMaxWidth(80);
            arrow.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
            arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_active);


            row.addView(originalViews[i]);
            row.addView(arrow);
            row.addView(distortedViews[i]);
            table.addView(row);
        }
```

I hope you can give me a hint!

Comment: try changing layout_gravity attributes of ur table layout, and also setScaleType in the program , if possible give a link to ur screenshot (as you cant post it currently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by surrounding the `TableLayout` with a `LinearLayout`

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/uyi_choosepi_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/uyi_gallery_originals"
        android:layout_above="@id/uyi_choosepi_buttontable">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/uyi_choosepi_tablelayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:shrinkColumns="0,1,2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a GridView instead that may get you further towards your goal. I saw [this blog post][1] recently, and I would have approached it more along these lines.

Edit: I meant to paste this tutorial sorry, http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/09/custom-gridview-ii-with-imageview-and.html